# Html <video> not playing in Samsung TV

Tags: html, video, television

I have one web page (React.js) with video on background.

```
    <video
        autoPlay
        muted
        loop
        className="public-layout-video"
        src="/video.mp4"
    />
```

I tested webpage on mobile, tablet, desktop and video is working. But when I run webpage in my Smart TV (Samsung Q80) browser, in the background is black screen and video not playing.

Solve somebody similar issue? I have integration to sentry and I checked logs but no logs found.

Comment: Have you been into the TV settings?  I wonder your TV thinks this is some kind of unathorised or out-of-region content? Or maybe even a parental setting? If the video is working on all other devices then there must be something going on with the Samsung browser.

Comment: On mobile/tablet/desktop was the video working on Chrome browser (via Windows PC or Android)?

Comment: On mobile (Android, chrome) - video working, on tablet (Android, chrome) video working, on desktop (Windows, chrome) video working, on laptop (Linux chrome - video working)

Comment: I'll try to take a look at the TV settings, thanks in advance Cutey from Cute Code